# terraform-kubernetes-provider how to create secret similar to a secret created from a file

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl

I am trying to simulate the kubectl commands in TF.

Kubectl command

```
kubectl create secret generic cloud-access \
  --from-file=basic.txt=$TUTORIAL_HOME/creds-sasl-user.txt
```

Contents of creds-sasl-user.txt

```
username=<api-key>
password=<api-secret>
```

In my Terraform run, I have the API key and API secret created but I am not sure how I can simulate the exact behaviour. This is what I have so far but doesn't seems correct to me

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "k8s_secret" {
  metadata {
    namespace = var.namespace
    name      = var.secret_name
  }
  data = {
    basic.txt           = "username=${var.api_key}password=${var.api_secret}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official TF documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings), You can use `<<EOT` to pass multi line string like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "k8s_secret" {
  metadata {
    namespace = "default"
    name      = "test"
  }
  data = {
  "basic.txt"           = <<EOT
username=<api-key>
password=<api-secret>
  EOT
  }
}
```

Don't forget to place Secret's key (`basic.text`) within the quotes before applying.